# Copy objects from range of environments to target environment R

Tags: r, nested-for-loop

I have organized dataframes in several environments, each organised in lists. I now want to search for each dataframe from a given set of dataframe names, determine whether the name exists in a particular list name of each of the environments, and if yes, copy that object to the target list of a target environment.

In the example below I created 2 environments A and B where the search should be applied to, and environment Z as result environment.

Something about the content of the local environments: Both A and B have some df's within one or 2 lists. The list names (I and II) refer to a certain analysis phase I and II.  The main lists are not always both present in a local environment, and the search in a local environment should stop if the dataframe has been found in list II (if not then list I should be searched).
Important is that the output object should be overwritten if the function is reapplied.

```
# Create Environments
Env_A <- new.env(parent = emptyenv())  
Env_B <- new.env(parent = emptyenv())  

# Environments to apply search ####
Env_list_search <- c(Env_A, Env_B)

# Target Environment
Env_Z <- new.env(parent = emptyenv())

# Create objects to search for (within lists)
Env_A$I$df_A <- "details df_A"
Env_A$I$df_B <- "details df_B"
Env_A$II$df_A <- "details df_A"

Env_B$I$df_C <- "details df_C"
Env_B$II$df_B <- "details df_B"

# Scope of dataframes to search for:
Dataframe_search <- c("df_A","df_C")
```

My idea is to create two vectors for the search:

- One having the dataframe names to search for
- One having the environment names to apply the search

The search above should result in Env_Z showing:
II$df_A and
II$df_C

My idea was to create a for loop (for the environment search) within a for loop (for the dataframe search) but I am stuck in the setup:

Questions I have:

1. How to quote the name of the local environments in object "Env_list_search"
2. How to refer to a local environment in the loop
3. How to create the loop within a loop

What I so far created (unfinished and with errors):

```
for(i in Dataframe_search) {
  
  for(j in Env_list_search) {
    
    # When dataframes occurs in list II
    if(has_name(j$II,Dataframe_search[[i]]) == T) {
      
      Env_Z$II[[Dataframe_search[[i]] <- j$II$Dataframe_search[[i]]
      
      return(
        Env_Z = Env_Z
      )
    } else {
      
      # When dataframes occurs in list I
      if(has_name(j$I,Dataframe_search[[i]]) == T) {
        
        Env_Z$I[[Dataframe_search[[i]] <- j$I$Dataframe_search[[i]]
        #)
        
        return(
          Env_Z = Env_Z
          
        )
      } else {
        
        
        return()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm...I am not sure if I understand your question. Can you share what would be your expected output for the data shared?

Comment: The expected output is an overview of dataframes in the target environment (Env_Z) for the dataframes named in the search set (Dataframe_search). The local environments (Env_A, Env_B) currently have lots of dataframes and other objects and I want to bring some key dataframes to a sort of summary environment (Env_Z). So Env_Z shows a copy of the dataframes found in the local environments named in the seach list (Env_list_search).  Then

Comment: As the local environments are organised in two lists (named I and II) and the dataframe can appear in either one or both of them there is a rule to apply to take the dataframe from list II if exists and otherwise from I (if exists). I hope I clarified enough.

Comment: I think you should try to learn the correct functions for handling environments when they are referred to by 'character' values. E.g. `class('Env_A')
[1] "character"`  wrong ;  `class(get('Env_A')) #[1] "environment"` right.  In addition to looking at `?get` your should also look at `?apropos`. You may find useful utility functions in the `rlang` package. In the course of creating portions of the tidyverse, Hadley needed to teach himself, and then teach his acolytes, the somewhat arcane aspects of how the R language represents and expresses different levels of abstraction.

Comment: I'm also nominating the question as it stands for closure. It seems too broad. I think my comment above demonstrates that there are multiple areas of misunderstanding that need to be clarified and this seems to be a request to complete a multi-level project outline where many of the components are not yet created in code. It is also using functions that do not exist in base R installations, e.g. `has_name`